# Page width adapt to uiwebview width

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, uiwebview, width

I want to display a simple webpage with text in a uiwebview narrower than the iphone screen. It is a webview with a bar on the left so I have a problem with my webpages because I need to use horizontal scroll to browse them. I want it to scale to the space it has.

I have tried with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
```

Also with width=device-width, initial-scale = 1... But I find the same problem after all.

I found that if I quit meta tag, it renders fine but text is so small that I can't read it on my mobile phone.

Comment: i think i understand what you mean, it a bit big and doesnt fit?? - if so, scale it down till it fits -- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.7, maximum-scale=0.7">

Comment: That worked! Thank you. But I have a doubt with this. In case the screen is bigger or smaller (let say an android screen) Should I need to modify scale to adapt to each screen? Or the browser adapts automatically?

Comment: Well, usually  there are 3 or more versions of an App. One for small screens, one for HD screens and one for Tablets. On Google play store for example you can upload versions of your App that will run on different Models and screens.